# How to do a backup in oracle with data and without data?

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle19c, datapump

I have been asked to make a backup of type export: full or schema and default, structure and only data in oracle.

I found these example commands to backup database and schema

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log
```

```
expdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

What options should I add to make a backup with data and without data?

What is a default backup?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `content` parameter you're looking for. [Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL838) is, basically, what you should study.

> CONTENT=[ALL | DATA_ONLY | METADATA_ONLY]
>
> - ALL unloads both data and metadata. This is the default.
> - DATA_ONLY unloads only table row data; no database object definitions are unloaded.
> - METADATA_ONLY unloads only database object definitions; no table row data is unloaded (...)

Default is `ALL`.